# How to generate html report directly from R script?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, reporting

I have a R script, say myscript.R, which does a lot of stuff and the final output is a list object with many different components.
I'd like to pass the list to a function which generate a html report "injecting" the various components in a preformatted template.
the code is something like this:

```
main_fun = function() {

  # do some stuff 

  d1 = list(
    a = 42,
    b = "foo",
    c = c("elem1","elem2","elem3")
  )

  generate_report(d1)
}

generate_report = function(data) {
  # generate html report
}
```

(actually obviously the value of the components of the list is the output of the "do some stuff" part)

I'm new to R Markdown and knitr, there is a way to dynamically generate the html report calling a function within the code? without a .rmd markdown file and without passing the entire script to a function like

```
rmarkdown::render('myscript.R')
```

Comment: I guess I'm missing why to do the analysis in a separate script at all.... why not just have a traditional `Rmd` file that generates the HTML doc?

Comment: @duckmayr Because the main script, actually, is very complex and does a lot of stuff, that part of code is untouchable and is meant to be structured as native R code. The reporting is only the final step and I want to keep that part as a "separate module".
In addition, I'd like to be able to dinamically generate more than one report

Answer (score 0):

This solution takes code in form of a string and creates Rmd file and renders it to html:

Edit 1: I should also mention that I only tested this on RStudio...

````
my_markdown_rederer <- function(text) {

  rmd_file_name <- "temp.Rmd"

  yaml_header <- "---
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    fig_caption: true
    theme: flatly
---"

  content <- paste0(yaml_header,
                    "\n",
                    "\n",
                    "```{r, echo=FALSE}\n",
                    text,
                    "\n",
                    "```\n")

  write(content, rmd_file_name)

  rmarkdown::render(rmd_file_name)
  utils::browseURL(paste0("file://", utils::URLencode(gsub("Rmd$", "html", rmd_file_name))))
}


text <- 'd1 = list(
  a = 42,
  b = "foo",
  c = c("elem1","elem2","elem3"))

  d1'

my_markdown_rederer(text)
````

Edit 2: We can also directly use an already existing .R file

```
text <- 'd1 = list(
  a = 42,
  b = "foo",
  c = c("elem1","elem2","elem3"))

  d1'

# Create .R file for example where we make html from an existing file
# 
fileConn <- file("file_with_original_pure_R_code.R")
writeLines(text, fileConn)
close(fileConn)



# Example using an existing .R file
# 
file_handler <- file("file_with_original_pure_R_code.R")
text <- paste0(readLines(file_handler), collapse="\n")
close(file_handler)
my_markdown_rederer(text)
```

Edit 3: The yaml header might not even be neccessary